# C# Is there a way to cast 2 events in a function?

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to make one function that will do some instructions for 2 (mouse) events in a DataGridView.
In order to not repeat the instructions in both of events.

Here is my code:

```
        private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
            { Process.Start(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string); }
        }

        private void dgv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
            { Process.Start(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string); }
        }
```

So far I've tried to do this:

```
        private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            ReLink(e);
        }

        private void dgv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ReLink(e);
        }

        //no matter which event I will specify, it is clear that it will only work for one event
        private void ReLink(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
            { Process.Start(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value as string); }
        }
```

So, is there a way to solve this?...

Comment: Simple solution: Pass RowIndex and ColumnIndex as two separate int parameters. Then only the caller cares about “e”, or the type it has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can go ahead with this

```
    private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        ReLink(e.ColumnIndex ,e.RowIndex);
    }

    private void dgv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ReLink(e.ColumnIndex ,e.RowIndex);
    }

    //no matter which event I will specify, it is clear that it will only work for one event
    private void ReLink(int colIndex, int rowIndex)
    {
        if (colIndex >= 0 && rowIndex >= 0 && dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex] is DataGridViewLinkCell)
        { Process.Start(dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value as string); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex can be passed to the ReLink function instead of the type of event args.